# Optimization [Finding Maximum with Negative Exponents]

Tags: calculus, optimization

I currently have a problem that I am stuck on. I can't figure out what to do with these negative exponents.

The problem is...

12. Suppose production is as described above, with $m(c,l) = A·c^α l^{1−α}$, $0 < α < 1$, but now with $α = 0.5$ and $c + 12l = 300$. What combination of $c$ and $l$ yield the greatest amount produced?

This is my work so far...

$m(c,l) = A·c^α l^{1−α}$, $0 < α < 1$
$α = 0.5$
$c + 12l = 300$
Maximize!

I believe that we disregard A in this problem as the problem fails to mention any value for A.

$$c = 300 - 12l$$
$$m(c,l) = m(l)$$
\begin{align}
m(l) &= (300-12l)^0.5·l^1-0.5\\
     &= (300-12l)^0.5·l^0.5\\
m'(l) &= 0.5 (300-12l)^{-0.5}(-12) + 0.5l^{-0.5}(300-12l)^{0.5}\\
dm/dl &= 0 = 0.5(300-12l)^{-0.5}(-12) + 0.5l^{-0.5}(300-12l)0.5\\
\end{align}

Right here is where I didn't know what to do. I don't know if I could multiply $(-12)$ by $0.5(300-12l)^{-0.5}$ and get $-6(300-12l)^{-0.5}$

I know that the negative exponents formula is $a^{-n} = 1/a^n$ but don't really know how to use it with this particular problem.

Can anyone help me with the next steps here to find the Maximum?

After I solve for l, I should be able to plug it in and solve for $c$ to get my answer but I'm just confused with all the negative exponents.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Please use mathjax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting the constraint into the objective function the problem becomes

$$ \max_l A(300-12l)^\alpha l^{1-\alpha}.$$

The first order condition is

$$ -12\alpha A(300-12l)^{\alpha-1} l^{1-\alpha} + (1-\alpha)A(300-12l)^\alpha l^{-\alpha} = 0, $$

which implies (divide by $A(300-12l)^{\alpha} l^{-\alpha}$)

$$ -12\alpha(300-12l)^{-1} l  +(1-\alpha) = 0, $$

and therefore (multiply by $(300-12l)$)

$$ 12\alpha l   = (1-\alpha)(300-12l), $$

and finally (solve for $l$)

$$ l^* = 25(1-\alpha).$$

The optimal level for $c$ can be obtained by substituting the $l^*$ into the constraint, which leads to

$$c^*=300-12*25(1-\alpha)=300\alpha.$$

Comment: Hi mzp, thank you so much for your reply. However, I'm still a little bit confused by your work. Why did you not plug in 0.5 for α? I'm also not understanding what the first order condition is nor the objective function is. I just thought I were to find the derivative and find the critical point where f'(x)=0. Could you explain your work a little bit more? Thanks!!

Comment: Also, sorry for the typos in the problem. I am new to math stackexchange.

Comment: @m.daoo You can plug $\alpha = 0.5$. The first order condition is exactly $f'(x)=0$ where $f(x)$ is the objective function.

Comment: I see how you got the objective function but the steps from first order condition all the way down, I got lost. :/

Comment: @m.daoo I added some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, you want to maximize $$f(l)=A\, c^\alpha\, l^{1-\alpha}$$ where $c$ is a function of $l$.

So, $$f'(l)=Al^{-\alpha } c^{\alpha -1} \left(\alpha  l c'+(1-\alpha)  c\right)$$ and, since this corresponds to maximimum, then $$\alpha  l c'+(1-\alpha)  c=0$$ Now, using $c=300-12l$, $c'=-12$ and $$-12 \alpha  l+(1-\alpha)(300-12l)=0$$ Solving for $l$ leads to $l=25(1-\alpha)$ to which corresponds $c=300\alpha$.

Now, use the $\alpha$ you want or need.